# Using ModelSerializer with joined records

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a tool for drawing diagrams on the web. I have a model like so:

```
class PlaneableItem(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=NAME_LENGTH, blank=True)

class View(PlaneableItem):
    # Some useful details

class Anchor(Model):
    view = models.ForeignKey(View)
    planeable = models.ForeignKey(PlaneableItem)

class BlockRepresentation(Anchor):
    # Useful details

class LineRepresentation(Anchor):
    # Useful details
```

I try to make a rest API that returns lists of all blocks and lines for a specific view, including the name of the planeable that they refer to.

I can get a queryset for this using:

```
qs = BlockRepresentation.objects.filter(view=theview).all()
qs.select_related('planeable')
qs.extra(select={'name': 'rest_api_planeableitem.name'})
```

However, now I can't use a ModelSerializer on it, because the field 'name' is not part of the BlockRepresentation.

I really like ModelSerializers, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you need that `extra()` call? If the sole purpose of that call is to rename a field, you can omit that from the queryset and rename the field using a [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) from your serializer. I will assume `planeable` is the ForeignKey field in `BlockRepresentation` model to the `PlaneableItem` model. Sample code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class BlockRepresentationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Some fields
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BlockRepresentation

    def get_name(self, obj):
        if obj.planeable:
            return obj.planeable.name
        return ''
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the SerializerMethodField, I was trying to solve it in the queryset. But this probably do! Thanks!